# rspec seems to get a different header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am new to rspec and have had a lot of trouble getting things working on my system (OS X, 10.7.4).  I finally got rspec running but I am getting errors when there shouldn't be any.

Simple test of a header title below

```
  it "should have the right title" do
    get 'home'
    response.should have_selector("title",:content=>"YOUniversity Admin Home")
  end
```

Failures:

```
1) AdminController GET 'home' should have the right title
   Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",:content=>"YOUniversity Admin Home")
   expected following output to contain a <title>YOUniversity Admin Home</title> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
 # ./spec/controllers/admin_controller_spec.rb:13
```

The app displays the proper title when run.  The layout appears to have a different header DOCTYPE field however.  Here's the header in the layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>YOUniversity Admin <%= @title %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<!--[if IE 6]<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie6' %><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie7' %><![endif]-->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Notice that the DOCTYPE does not include all that other information shown in the response.

I'm puzzled as to how that could happen. I have verified that the title is correct by running the app.

Any ideas?

-Michael

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
render_views
```

right after the first describe block. Specs in spec/controllers don't render view by default.